# Open react native app from email link for reset password implementation

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I have implemented a react native app with deep linking implementation. I have successfully open my app using

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d sports://sport`

this command open app in simulator, So deep linking concept working fine.

But how to open the app in mobile while clicking on email link.

Is anyone know how link is build for sending in email and once i click on email link from mobile my app open?

I have also installed "Deep link Tester" app from google app store and running same link on it which will opening my app successfully.

**Code for Android setup**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="sports" android:host="sport" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have added intent-filter in activity tag of AndroidManifest.xml file.

**What I want to achieve**:

When user press forgot password from mobile app, I will send email with token for reset there password. So when user click on email link I want to open my app and redirect him to reset password route

**What is problem**:

I am not able to open react-native app from mail

Comment: Looking solution for the same problem

Comment: @kalpeshdeo please review my answer and follow step given into it. Now i am able to open my app from reset password mail and verification mail.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve deep linking in react native with help of [Branch.io provide solution for deep linking for mobile app](https://docs.branch.io/)

**Solution**

I follow step given in below link of branch.io

[React native implementation for deep linking with branch.io](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/)

With this step now i am able to open my app from emails with route implementation for open different pages in my app.

Comment: Could you share your code?